# “Proxying” a lot of HTTP requests with Node.js + Express 2

Tags: node.js, http, proxy, express

I'm writing proxy in Node.js + Express 2. Proxy should:

1. decrypt POST payload and issue HTTP request to server based on result;
2. encrypt reply from server and send it back to client.

Encryption-related part works fine. The problem I'm facing is timeouts. Proxy should process requests in less than 15 secs. And most of them are under 500ms, actually.

Problem appears when I increase number of parallel requests. Most requests are completed ok, but some are failed after 15 secs + couple of millis. `ab -n5000 -c300` works fine, but with concurrency of 500 it fails for some requests with timeout.

I could only speculate, but it seems thant problem is an order of callbacks exectuion. Is it possible that requests that comes first are hanging until `ETIMEDOUT` because of node's focus in latest ones which are still being processed in time under 500ms.

P.S.: There is no problem with remote server. I'm using [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) for interactions with it.

**upd**

The way things works with some code:

```js
function queryRemote(req, res) {
  var options = {};  // built based on req object (URI, body, authorization, etc.)
  request(options, function(err, httpResponse, body) {
    return err ? send500(req, res)
               : res.end(encrypt(body));
  });
}

app.use(myBodyParser);  // reads hex string in payload
                        // and calls next() on 'end' event

app.post('/', [checkHeaders,   // check Content-Type and Authorization headers
               authUser,       // query DB and call next()
               parseRequest],  // decrypt payload, parse JSON, call next()
         function(req, res) {
  req.socket.setTimeout(TIMEOUT);
  queryRemote(req, res);
});
```

My problem is following: when `ab` issuing, let's say, 20 POSTs to `/`, express route handler gets called like thousands of times. That's not always happening, sometimes 20 and only 20 requests are processed in timely fashion.

Of course, `ab` is not a problem. I'm 100% sure that only 20 requests sent by `ab`. But route handler gets called multiple times.

I can't find reasons for such behaviour, any advice?

Comment: Can you share some code? How things are being handled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Timeouts were caused by using [`http.globalAgent`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_globalagent) which by default can process [up to 5](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_agent_maxsockets) concurrent requests to one `host:port` (which isn't enough in my case).

Thouthands of requests (instead of tens) were sent by `ab` (Wireshark approved fact under OS X; I can not reproduce this under Ubuntu inside Parallels).

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at [node-http-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy) module and how it handles the connections. Make sure you don't buffer any data and everything works by [streaming](https://github.com/substack/stream-handbook). And you should try to see where is the time spent for those long requests. Try instrumenting parts of your code with [`conosle.time`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/all.html#all_console_time_label) and [`console.timeEnd`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/all.html#all_console_timeend_label) and see where is taking the most time. If the time is mostly spent in javascript you should try to profile it. Basically you can use v8 profiler, by adding --prof option to your node command. Which makes a [v8.log](http://code.google.com/p/v8/wiki/V8Profiler#Process_the_Generated_Output) and can be processed via a [v8 tool found in node-source-dir/deps/v8/tools](http://code.google.com/p/v8/wiki/V8Profiler#Process_the_Generated_Output). It only works if you have installed d8 shell via [scons](http://www.scons.org/)(scons d8). You can have a look at [this article](http://blog.arc90.com/2012/03/05/profiling-node-programs-on-mac-os-x/) to help you further to make this working.

You can also use [node-webkit-agent](https://github.com/c4milo/node-webkit-agent) which uses webkit developer tools to show the profiler result. You can also have a look at [my fork](https://github.com/alfred-nsh/node-webkit-agent) with a bit of sugar.

If that didn't work, you can try [profiling with dtrace](http://blog.nodejs.org/2012/04/25/profiling-node-js/)(only works in illumos-based systems like SmartOS).

Comment: I should read payload, decrypt it, and send further to remote server. Then I read reply from remote, encrypt it and send back. Most time is IO with remote. But what I'm facing is following: let's say ab sends 20 request, but express calls route callback way too much times (like thousand times). Any advice on that?

Comment: That doesn't seem right. Maybe in one of the middlewares multiple times you call the callback(`next`). Check all of them. And looking at your code, you should be streaming(as opposed to now), but you can't use express midllewares like that.

Comment: **Firstly**, I can't stream. I need to have whole body to decrypt, whole remote response to encrypt. I mean yeah, I could stream hex to cipher, and, from there, decrypted body to remote and back, but that's just pain in the ass (+ authorization would be tricky to implement). So I stick with current approach. **Secondly**, I can't use express middleware how, exactly?

Comment: Express is not built for streaming, but nevermind it. I can see your pain now. One more thing I forgot, it could be garbage collector pauses that make your app slow. You add `--trace_gc` option, and see how much each garbage collection take.